# HANA SQL select count and and array for ids

Tags: sql, hana

Is there any way to generate a query where I can have 2 fields. First field is get the count and second is to get the names as an array?

Sample Table:

```
|---------------------|------------------|
|          id         |       name       |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          1          |       John       |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          2          |       Doe        |
|---------------------|------------------|
```

And then, I can get results as:

```
|---------------------|------------------|
|        count        |   array_name     |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          2          |  ["John", "Doe"] |
|---------------------|------------------|
```

Comment: what is your dbms

Comment: Please tag the database you are using.

Comment: it's hana. @Abhishek already tagged. thanks

Comment: Hana doesn't support arrays, so your question is meaningless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the below - using `STRING_AGG()`

```
SELECT count(id), STRING_AGG(name,',' ORDER BY id)AS array_name
FROM tablename
```